# Bootstrap, how can I make two tables the same "width"

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I got two tables as this:

[image: tables]

I want them to have the same width, I don't know what it's called but you can see that the columns dosn't have the same width.

Here is my code for it:

```
    <aside>
    <table class="table table-bordered" style="margin: 0;">
        <thead>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="tableHeader">Pilot ID</td>
            <td><?php echo 'SAS ' . $results['id'];?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="tableHeader">First Name</td>
            <td><?php echo $results['firstname'];?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="tableHeader">Last Name</td>
            <td><?php echo $results['lastname'];?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="tableHeader">Age</td>
            <td>17</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="tableHeader">Distance Flown</td>
            <td>3790 km</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="tableHeader">Flights</td>
            <td><?php echo $results['flights'];?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="tableHeader">Flight Hours</td>
            <td><?php echo $results['flighttime'];?></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <table class="table table-bordered style="margin: 0;"">
    <thead>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="tableHeader">737-600</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="tableHeader">737-700</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="tableHeader">737-800</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="tableHeader">A319</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="tableHeader">A320</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="tableHeader">A321</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="tableHeader">A330</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="tableHeader">A340</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="tableHeader">CRJ-900</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="tableHeader">ATR-600</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="tableHeader">717</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="tableHeader">SAB 2000</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
</aside>
```

JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/ncqmy09c/

Comment: 1) div.row // 2) div.col-xs-6*2 // 3)you tables....

like this -> https://jsfiddle.net/ncqmy09c/2/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could do.

```
.table {
    table-layout: fixed;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vawtr0u5/

Answer (score 1):

1) div.row.

2) div.col-xs-6*2.

3) you tables....

like this -> [Example jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ncqmy09c/2/)

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <table class="table table-bordered" style="margin: 0;">
            TABLE 1
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <table class="table table-bordered" style="margin: 0;">
            TABLE 2
        </table>        

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the [HTML col width Attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_col_width.asp)

```
<table class="table table-bordered" style="margin: 0;">
  <col width="100">
  <col width="100">
  <thead>
      ...
  </thead>
  <tbody>
     ...
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ncqmy09c/1/